# Why don't wildcards work inside a function?

Tags: r

I have a function that creates data frames which I need to rename and concatenate into one data frame. I am trying to use wildcards to identify all the data frames I need to combine. Here is a greatly simplified version of the function:

```
func <- function() {
    df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(16), 1))
    hi_1 <<- df
    
    df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(16), 1))
    hi_2 <<- df
    
    df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(16), 1))
    hi_3 <<- df
    
    nameswant <<- grep('hi_', ls(), value=T)
    dfwant <<- ldply(nameswant, get)
    
    rm(list=ls(pattern=glob2rx("hi_*")))
}
func()
```

When I run this, however, it gives me an empty data frame and does not delete the individual created data frames (which I gave double arrows to because without them it errors that it can't find them. If I run the individual lines outside of a function they work fine. What is it about the function that breaks this?

Comment: If you are wondering why I am doing this, please trust I have good reason but context is stripped to make a reproduceable example.

Comment: Saving separate objects to the global environment and later combining them is an anti-pattern and is almost certainly not the best approach here. If the function is creating the objects why do you need to search for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `ls()` function is only examining the local environment, e.x. the function's environment and not the global environment.

Try adding the `envir = globalenv()` option to the `ls()` calls like:

```
nameswant <<- grep('hi_', ls(envir = globalenv()), value=T)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to assign variables in the enclosing environment you should `ls(..., env = parent.frame())` to find them. (`ls()` without `env` lists objects *within the current scope* only ...)

For what it's worth I think `mget(nameswant)` will do the same as `ldply(nameswant, get)` without inducing a dependence on the `plyr` package ...

FWIW when I run your function without global assignment it seems to work fine:

```r
func <- function() {
    df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(16), 1))
    hi_1 <- df
    
    df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(16), 1))
    hi_2 <- df
    
    df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(16), 1))
    hi_3 <- df
    
    nameswant <- grep('hi_', ls(), value=TRUE)
    dfwant <- mget(nameswant)
    
    rm(list=ls(pattern = glob2rx("hi_*")))
}
func()
```

More generically you could avoid the anti-pattern of creating a bunch of objects in the (local) environment and *then* collecting them into a list: the following version should get you to the same place with less fuss ...

```r
func <- function() {
    dfwant <- list()

    df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(16), 1))
    dfwant[["hi_1"]] <- df
    
    df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(16), 1))
    dfwant[["hi_2"]] <- df
    
    df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(16), 1))
    dfwant[["hi_3"]] <- df
    
}
func()
```